# I can't find the names of students with a specific number of books

Tags: mysql

I have the tables below in my database:

```
Student    (Stud_no: string, Stud_name: string) 
Membership (Mem_no: string, Stud_no: string) 
Book       (book_no: string, book_name: string, author: string) 
Iss_rec    (iss_no: integer, iss_date: date, Mem_no: string, book_no: string)
```

I created the tables and inserted values.

Now I have to **List the students who reached the borrowed limit 3.(i.e., none can borrow more than 3 books)**

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT student.stud_name, COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Books'
FROM student, iss_rec, membership, book
WHERE student.stud_no = membership.stud_no
AND membership.Mem_no = iss_rec.Mem_no
AND book.book_no = iss_rec.book_no
GROUP BY student.stud_name
```

It shows the number of books each student borrowed. But how can I find the names only with 3 books?
**Also, what measure should I take so that, those students with 3 books can borrow no more books?**

Comment: (A) Use proper `join`s. (B) Search your training materials for `having`.

Comment: just add  having count(*)=3

Answer (score 0):

for aggreated  result you can use having for filters the value

```
SELECT student.stud_name, COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Books'
FROM student, iss_rec, membership, book
WHERE student.stud_no = membership.stud_no
AND membership.Mem_no = iss_rec.Mem_no
AND book.book_no = iss_rec.book_no
GROUP BY student.stud_name
having  COUNT(*) > 3
```

or for 3 book

```
SELECT student.stud_name, COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Books'
FROM student, iss_rec, membership, book
WHERE student.stud_no = membership.stud_no
AND membership.Mem_no = iss_rec.Mem_no
AND book.book_no = iss_rec.book_no
GROUP BY student.stud_name
having  COUNT(*) =  3
```

Comment: But what about the solution of the second part? I am using Trigger, but it's not upto the mark.

Comment: Your comment have not sens to me  ..........what's mean  the second part???  and trigger?  ..

Comment: I told about the "Also, what measure should I take so that, those students with 3 books can borrow no more books?" part

Comment: there are not many possibilities .. you can check the number of books you have already borrowed when the user logs in or before inserting a new request in both cases must include a control function (it could be an adaptation of the same query in my answer) .. that you can call when you need it .. if the check function gives you the ok then proceed otherwise issue a signal to the user